# Markov Chain Eigenvalues Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose $M$ is a reversible Markov chain with respect to $\pi$, on the finite set $X$. Note, operator M defined by $Mg(x)=\sum_y M(x,y)g(y)$, where $g$ is a real-valued function. Show that if M is not periodic, then $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of M.

Proof:
All we have to show is that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $M$. We do this by contradiction.
Note that the definition of $M$ being aperiodic means for every $x,y \in X$ that $gcd(\{n: M^{n}(x,y)>0\})=1$

Now, suppose by contradiction that $f$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $-1$. Thus $Mf=-f$. Choose $x^*$ satisfying $|f(x^{*})| \geq |f(y)|$ for all $y\in X$.
We have then that $f(x^{*})=-Mf(x^{*})=-\sum_y M(x^{*},y)f(y)$.
This implies that $f(y)=-f(x^{*})$ for all $y$ with $M(x^{*},y)>0$. Thus all values of $f$ one step from $x^{*}$ are equal to $-f(x^{*})$.

So apparently, all of the steps are correct and do not need further justification. However, apparently I am missing a step now to finish the proof and show that the period of the state $x^{*}$ is greater than 1. Specifically, I need to show that the period of $x^{*}$ is even. That is, I need to show that the $gcd(\{n:M^{n}(x^{*},x^{*})>0\})=2k$ for some positive integer $k$ (period is even).
Thus, I am just not sure how to complete the proof. 
How does $f(y)=-f(x^{*})$ for all $y$ with $M(x^{*},y)>0$ imply that the period of $x^{*}$ is even, $gcd(\{n:M^{n}(x^{*},x^{*})>0\})=2k$ for some positive integer $k$? (really, I just have to prove the period is $\geq 2$, so that it is not aperiodic). Any help to help finish this last step to complete the proof would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: hi, does anyone have any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Not quite sure about the solution, but you haven't used the fact that $M$ is reversible.  Remember, the detailed balance equation states that there exists a probability distribution $\pi$ over $X$ such that for $x,y \in X$, we have
$$
\pi(x)M(x,y) = \pi(y)M(y,x).
$$

Comment: One way to show that the period must be even is to show that if $y_1,y_2$ are both $k$ steps away from $x^*$, then we must have $M(y_1,y_2) = 0$.  I don't see a quick way to do this here, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick observation: since $f$ is an eigenvector (by definition non-zero), we must have $f(x^*) \neq 0$.

I'll now extend your argument a bit: for any integer $k \geq 1$, we have 
$$
f(x^*) = (-1)^k M^k f(x^*) = (-1)^k\sum_{y}M^k(x^*,y) f(y)
$$
so we must have $f(y) = (-1)^k f(x^*)$ for all $y$ such that there is a walk of length $k$ from $x^*$ to $y$ of non-zero probability.

Now, suppose (for the purpose of contradiction) that $x^*$ does not have an even period.  That is, we suppose that for some odd number $2n+1$, we have $M^{2n+1}(x^*,x^*) > 0$.  So, there exists an odd cycle at $x^*$ with non-zero probability: that is, there is a sequence $ x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{2n},x_{2n+1}$ with $x_0=x_{2n+1} = x^*$ such that $M(x_i,x_{i+1}) > 0$ for $i = 0,1,\dots,2n$.

Consider $x_1$.  Since $M(x^*,x_1) > 0$, we must have $f(x_1) = -f(x^*)$.  On the other hand, the existence of our cycle means that 
$$
M^{2n}(x_1,x^*) \geq M(x_1,x_2) M(x_2,x_3) \cdots M(x_{2n},x^*)> 0
$$ 
which is to say that $M^{2n}(x_1,x^*) > 0$. The fact that $M$ is reversible means that $M^{2n}(x^*,x_1) > 0$. By the earlier argument, this means that $f(x_1) = (-1)^{2n}f(x^*) = f(x^*)$.  That is, we have concluded that
$$
f(x_1) = f(x^*) = -f(x^*)
$$
which is impossible since $f(x^*)$ is non-zero.  The conclusion follows.

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom thanks for the response. I'm not sure what is meant by "odd cycle". So since you show that it is impossible for there to exist an odd cycle with non-zero probability, are you saying that period of x* must be even? Also, when you say that there is a sequence $x^{*}=x_0,x_1..x_{2n+1}=x^{*}$,  does this mean $x^{*}=x_0$ and $x^{*}=x_{2n+1}$? could you explain what this sequence means and how its existence relates to there being odd cycle with >0 probability. Also finally could you tell me how you get that $f(x^{*})=(-1)^{k}M^{k}f(x^{*})$. Thanks and sorry for all the questions

Comment: Regarding the odd cycle: as you said, we're trying to show that $\gcd(\{n:M^{n}(x^{*},x^{*})>0\})=2k$.  In other words, we're trying to show that the set $\{n:M^{n}(x^{*},x^{*})>0\}$ contains no odd numbers.  In other words, we're trying to show that for every odd $m$ (or for every $m = 2n+1$), we have $M^m(x^*,x^*) = 0$

Comment: Now, if $M^m(x^*,x^*) > 0$, then there exists a sequence $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{m}$ with $x_0 = x_m = x^*$ such that 
$$
M(x_0,x_1)M(x_1,x_2) \cdots M(x_{m-1},x_m) > 0
$$
since $M^m(x^*,x^*)$ is by definition the sum of all such probabilities.  In other words, $M^m(x^*,x^*) = 0$ if and only if there is no walk of length $m$ that starts and ends with $x^*$ and has a non-zero probability.

Comment: To your last question: if $Mf = -f$, then we have $M^2f = M(Mf) = M(-f) = -Mf = f$, and more generally,
$$
M^k f = M^{k-1}(Mf) = -M^{k-1} f
$$
Inductively, this lets us conclude that $M^k f = (-1)^k f$, so that $M^k f(x^*) = (-1)^k f(x^*)$.

Comment: Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom thank you I understand much better than. Just to make sure so in your answer above you are assuming by contradiction that there is an odd cycle with non-zero probability. So does that mean that you are assuming $M^{2n+1}(x^{*},x^{*})>0$? And then are you saying that $(M^{2n+1}(x^{*},x^{*}))>0$ then implies that $M(x_0,x_1)>0, M(x_1,x_2)>0 ...M(x_{2n},x_{2n+1})>0$? When then also does the existence of our cycle imply that $M^{2n}(x_1,x^{*})>0$? Why does $M^{2n}>0$? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that $M^{2n+1}(x^*,x^*) > 0$, which means that there is at least one odd cycle with non-zero probability.  By my definition of an odd cycle, the fact that the cycle has non-zero probability implies that $M(x_0,x_1),M(x_1,x_2),\dots,M(x_{2n},x_{2n+1})$ are all non-zero.  Note that $M^{2n}(x_1,x^*) \geq M(x_1,x_2) \cdot M(x_2,x_3) \cdots M(x_{2n},x_{2n+1})$, and we just established that the probabilities on the right are non-zero.

Comment: Thanks @Omnomnomnom for all the help, it is clearer now. Just one last question, promise this to be my last question. But, I don't really understand why does the existence of our cycle imply that $M^{2n}(x_1,x^{*}) \geq M(x_1,x_2)*M(x_2,x_3)*...M(x_{2n},x_{2n+1})$. What is the reasoning/explanation behind this? (or intuition behind this) Thanks so much!

Comment: $M^{2n}(x_1,x^*) > 0$ if and only if there is a walk of length $2n$ of non-zero probability that starts at $x_1$ and ends at $x^*$.

Comment: Nevermind, I think it is clear now thanks.